# typeerror : val.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, insert, typeerror

I am running a mysql query to insert a record in a table.. but it is showing

> TypeError : val.slice is not a function.

```sql
    create table users( Userid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, uuid 
    varchar(255) NOT NULL, username varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    fullName varchar(255), password varchar(255), time TIMESTAMP, 
    isDeleted int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Userid));
```

```
    database.connection.query("INSERT INTO users (uuid, username, 
    fullName, password, time, isDeleted) VALUES(? , ?, ? , ?, ? , ?)", 
    [uuidv4, username, fullName, password, new Date().getTime(), 0], 
    function (error, result) {
                        if (error) {
                            LOG.error(error);
                            return resolve({ result: false });
                        }
                        else {
                            LOG.info("Username added.");
                            return resolve({ result: true });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Can you plz show the exact query running in console ?

Comment: @SagarJajoriya INSERT INTO users (uuid, username, 
    fullName, password, time, isDeleted) VALUES(? , ?, ? , ?, ? , ?)", 
    [uuidv4, username, fullName, password, new Date().getTime(), 0]

Comment: Not this one. I'm asking about the executed query on server. You can see on the console

Comment: @AarushiBhatia I don't think this error originated from this query. You should check the part of code where `val.slice` is used